# Swift: UIPanGestureRecognizer not working when called from another class

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, action, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController and I want to add a Pan Gesture Recognizer, What i'M Intending to do is to create another class that handles the gesture and further functions, so in the init() I get a reference to UIViewController.view then I add gesture recognizer, and its delegate is self.
but the problem is that gesture's action isn't firing. even though it fires when added from the UIViewController

here is a snippet of my code:

```
// Initializer of UISwipeView
init(Target target: UIView!) {
    super.init();

    // Keep reference to the given view (target)
    self.target = target;

    // if traget is't nill
    if(target != nil) {
        // Add Pan Gesture Recognizer
        gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UISwipeView.didPaned))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        self.target.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer);
    }
}
```

And here is how I use it from UIViewController's viewDidLoad() method

```
let swipeView: UISwipeView = UISwipeView(Target: self.view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to add the gesture recognizer to your swipeView (maybe you should rename your class, as it looks like part of UIKit with the name you've given it), and implement a delegate of the swipeView, so when the user swipes & UISwipeView.didPaned is called, you then inform the delegate that this has happened.

```
protocol SwipeViewDelegate: class {
    func userDidSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

In SwipeView:

```
class SwipeView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: SwipeViewDelegate?

    init(withFrame frame: CGRect, delegate: SwipeViewDelegate) {

        self.delegate = delegate

        super.init(frame: frame)

        // add your gesture recognizer stuff here
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SwipeView.didPan(_:))))

        // etc, etc
    }

    func didPan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        self.delegate?.userDidSwipe(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

In your viewController which adds the SwipeView, you have to implement the SwipeViewDelegate protocol, and pass yourself as the delegate when you instantiate the SwipeView.

(not had any chance to actually run any of this, hopefully no typos, etc)